# How do I position a child div absolute to a relative positioned parent div without breaking Bootstrap's image resizing in Firefox and IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-position

I'm using the Bootstrap framework, and I have a parent div containing an image with a `position:relative`, and a child div containing an image with a `position:absolute`. I'm using left and top with percentages to push the child div to the bottom right corner of the parent div.

In Chrome and Safari everything works as expected with the child div's positioning, and when the browser is re-sized the images respond and scale appropriately. However in Firefox and Internet Explorer, the image within the child div **fails** to re-size. It seems that `position:absolute` breaks Boostrap's image re-sizing functionality.

Does anyone know the correct way to handle this, or a work-around?

Live example: http://www.smartbombinteractive.com/testbed/bootstrap_resize/

**HTML:**

```
<div> class="header-image"><img src="img/img_test_bg.jpg">
        <div class="corner-peal"><img src="img/header_corner_peal.png">
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header-image{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.corner-peal{
    position:absolute;
    left:50.99%;
    top: 17.295%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such a noob! Bootstrap scales an image based upon the width of its' container. The solution is set the a percentage width on the child (Chrome and Safari will do this for you and Fire Fox and IE do not.)

```
.corner-peal{
    position:absolute;
    left:50.99%;
    top: 17.295%;
    width:49.01%;
}
```